# Sort dependent child array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort array based on child values, I want parent child array at first position then its child and then its grand child and so on... based on its "Parent" value
here is my example array,

```
$array= Array( 
            Array("self"=>"user4", "parent"=>"user6"),
            Array("self"=>"user2", "parent"=>"user1"),
            Array("self"=>"user1", "parent"=>"user4"),
            Array("self"=>"user5", "parent"=>"user2"),
            Array("self"=>"user6", "parent"=>"user3"),
            Array("self"=>"user3", "parent"=>"Parent") // it will be anything
        );
```

this array should be sorted like below

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [self] => user3
        [parent] => Parent
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [self] => user6
        [parent] => user3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [self] => user4
        [parent] => user6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [self] => user1
        [parent] => user4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [self] => user2
        [parent] => user1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [self] => user5
        [parent] => user2
    ))
```

Comment: You have not mentioned a pattern.Can you please add some actual output code so we can suggest.At the moment it is not clear you sort it on child value or parent value.

Comment: @ rajausman haider, I am sorting based on parent values, it can be anything, if that parent referring  to any child then it should come after parent, basically it is parent child pattern.

Comment: Can an item have more than one child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it in the following way:

```
$array= Array( 
            Array("self"=>"user4", "parent"=>"user6"),
            Array("self"=>"user2", "parent"=>"user1"),
            Array("self"=>"user1", "parent"=>"user4"),
            Array("self"=>"user5", "parent"=>"user2"),
            Array("self"=>"user6", "parent"=>"user3"),
            Array("self"=>"user3", "parent"=>"Parent") // it will be anything
        );
$result = "";
foreach($array as $val)
{
    if($val['parent']== 'Parent')
    {
        $result[] = $val;
        getNextNode($val['self']);
    }
}
function getNextNode($child)
{
    global $array;
    global $result;
    foreach($array as $val)
    {
        if($val['parent'] == $child)
        {
            $result[] = $val;
            getNextNode($val['self']);
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($result);
```

You get the desired result.

Comment: I don't think there is need to do this if PHP provides functions like *usort*

Answer (score 2):

please have a look [Topological Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). It can be useful for you

Comment: links can be commented it cannot be an answer

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you need to sort something in PHP on a non trivial way you should use an user defined sort function (http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php), like this one. Please note that if you want to preserve the array indexes you should use the *uasort* function instead of the *usort* function. This will keep your code short and clean.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if($a['parent'] == 'Parent' || $a['self'] == $b['parent'])
        return -1;
    if($b['parent'] == 'Parent' || $b['self'] == $a['parent'])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

$array= Array( 
        Array("self"=>"user4", "parent"=>"user6"),
        Array("self"=>"user2", "parent"=>"user1"),
        Array("self"=>"user1", "parent"=>"user4"),
        Array("self"=>"user5", "parent"=>"user2"),
        Array("self"=>"user6", "parent"=>"user3"),
        Array("self"=>"user3", "parent"=>"Parent") // it will be anything
    );

usort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

Here the `user` who hasn't a parent is defined with a "Parent" as `parent`, but it could be something like `false` in which case you just need to update the `cmp` function accordingly.

Sorry for the formatting, it is really hard on the phone. Please feel free to edit it.